# How to read the http post parameters with pyramid?

Tags: python-3.x, pyramid

How to read the http post parameters with pyramid?
I know how to do that in case the parameters concern a piece of json, but how should I read it in case it concerns a simple key=value pair?
Example of a http post request (testing with hurl.it):

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Length: 16
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: test.bydehand.com
User-Agent: runscope/0.1

id=tr_uH4yPGBahB
```

If I perform a print 'request.json_body" in code, it complaints, probably because it's not a piece of valid json:

```
  File "/home/develop/app/daisy/payment/payment_view.py", line 88, in payment_webhook
    logger.debug("Receiving a webhook payment request body: [%s]", str(request.json_body))
  File "/home/develop/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pyramid/request.py", line 237, in json_body
    return json.loads(text_(self.body, self.charset))
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/json/__init__.py", line 318, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/json/decoder.py", line 343, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/json/decoder.py", line 361, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError(errmsg("Expecting value", s, err.value)) from None
```

How can I read these key/value pairs and put them in a dict?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`request.body` contains the raw body. `request.POST` is a `MultiDict`  that contains the parsed values.

In your case, `request.POST['id']` would contain the value.

You can use `request.POST.get('id')` and `request.POST.getall('id')` if you're not sure if the value is there or if it may be there many times.